# Is it safe to "Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out template.pnp"

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, administration, pnp-powershell

I have a communication site collection inside our SharePoint online tenant. and i want to export this site and create a new site based on the exported template, so i am planning to run this command:-

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://***.com/sites/Filing/
Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out template.pnp
```

my questions are:-

1) is it safe to run this command? and will it affect the site been extracted?

2) will this export the site data?

3) how i can create a new site based on the output (the template.pnp)?

4) since i specify `-Out template.pnp` so where the `template.pnp` will get saved? inside `C:\`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. This will not modify the site at all, it will just export the template
2. No data will be included
3. You must first create a new site (or modify an existing one). You do that by using the command `Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path template.pnp`. [More details here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/apply-pnpprovisioningtemplate?view=sharepoint-ps)
4. This will use the current folder, but you can specify where you want it: `Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out c:\temp\output.xml`

I reccomend reading this to get a better overview of the possibilities of the provisioning engine:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/introducing-the-pnp-provisioning-engine

Comment: thanks for the helpful reply, but by `current folder` you mean `C:\windows\system32`?

Comment: The folder you are running the command from :-) I believe most shells defaults to your users home folder

Comment: sperrs ok thanks,, now the `Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate` return this error `Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate : Maximum retry attempts 10, has be attempted.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out template.pnp
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate], MaximumRetryAttemptedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Provisioning.Site.GetProvisioningTemplate`

Comment: Are you using the latest version of PnP Powershell? Since the error says "WriteError" - try specifying the output path to somewhere you know your user has access, e.g "-Out c:\temp\template.pnp"

Comment: i am using version `SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline 3.19.2003.0`

Comment: Did you try specifying the output folder?

Comment: i am running it now,, will let u know the results

Comment: now i am getting this error `PS C:\windows\system32> Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out c:\template.pnp`..Error 
`Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate : The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out c:\template.pnp
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Provisioning.Site.GetProvisioningTemplate`

Comment: Timeout perhaps? Try narrowing down what you export by using the Handlers flag (eg. "-Handlers Lists") - check the documentation for full syntax